# saving and deleting fileI/O

Tags: file-io, for-loop, dictionary, python-3.x

Two part question.

First, how can i change this(i've tried using 'for' but i cant figure it out) so that it saves like;
'key value' instead of '{key: value}'.

```
with open("phonebook.txt", "w") as x:
    json.dump(a, x)
```

Second, how do you delete from a file by using the users input.
I cannot see a way of changing this to delete from file instead of the dict 'a';

```
name = input("enter name of contact you want to delete: ")
if name in a:
    del a[name]
```

EDIT. This is what ive done now but it doesnt do whats expected ( i also tried adding the .readlines where x is but it just gets errors.

```
def save(a):
    with open("phonebook.txt", "w") as x:
        for k in a:
            json.dump(str(k)+" "+str(a[k]), x)

def load():
    a = {}
    with open("phonebook.txt", "r") as f:
        for l in f:
            a[l[0]] = l[1]
        print (a)
```

def save works fine (as far as i can see anyway)

Also i have tried c = l.split() and a[c[0]] = c[1]. Just doesnt want to work !

Answer (score 1):

#### First part

That's not JSON format.  Do not use it if you need something else.  Use plain text files, like

```
    with open("phonebook.txt","w") as file :
        for key, value in a.items() :
            file.write(str(key)+" "+str(value))
```

#### Second part

It looks you loaded the file into dictionary `a`.  In that case, you just need to write dictionary `a` back to the file after deleting.  If you have not loaded the file into the dictionary yet, you can do it with:

```
    a= {}
    with open("phonebook.txt") as file :
        for line in file.readlines() :
            content= line.split()
            a[content[0]]= content[1]
```

Comment: Im using json because 'a' is a dictionary.

Comment: I dont quite get what your saying on the second part. The file has not been loaded into a thats what i could do with help for .. Thanks

Comment: @StandingBird  Files can't be manipulated as easily as in-memory data structures.  Meaning:  load the file into a dictionary, do the deletions, and write the dictionary back to the file.

Comment: @StandingBird  You can write a dictionary to a file in many ways other than using `json`.  Especially if you don't like `json`'s format!

Comment: Ok i get what your saying. I dont quite know how to do that though. (beginner, only a few days learning). Could you point me in the right direction without telling me the exact code (if you get what im saying lol).

Comment: @StandingBird  Modified my answer to show you how to load the file.

Comment: Ok its a bit confusing , dont quite get whats happening in every line but that just means i need to go back to some tutorials/guides. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @StandingBird  Google the `readlines` method of Python files, the `split` method of Python `string`s, and how to add items to a dictionary.

Comment: with open("phonebook.txt", "w") as x:
        for k in a:
            json.dump(str(k)+" "+str(a[k]), x)